# Heat transport in an Axi-symmetric flow through a Thick Cylinder [BVP]

Tags: partial-differential-equations, problem-solving, mathematical-physics, boundary-value-problem, cylindrical-coordinates

A fluid passes through a cylindrical cavity with thick walls. A constant heat flux acts on the outer wall while the fluid is in thermal interaction with the inner wall. $T$ represents the solid temperature and the fluid counterpart is denoted by $T_f$.
$T$ is coupled with $T_f$ in the sense that they influence each other (In other words, the fluid cools the solid along its flow length ). While modelling this situation, I have reduced the phenomenon to the following PDE problem:

In the domain , $r\in[a_1,a_2]$ and $z\in[0,L]$ (considering axisymmetry, $\frac{\partial T}{\partial \theta}=0$) so $T=T(r,z)$

$a_1,a_2$ are the inner and outer radii of the cavity respectively while $L$ is the cylinder length. The boundary condition at $r=a_1$ takes into account the coupling between the two mediums.
$$
\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}=0
$$

is subjected to

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial z} \vert_{z=0} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial z} \vert_{z=L}=0$$

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \vert_{r=a_2}=\gamma$$

$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \vert_{r=a_1}=\delta\Bigg[T-\alpha e^{-\alpha z}\bigg(\int_0^z e^{\alpha s} T(r,s) \mathrm{d}s + \frac{A}{\alpha} \bigg)\Bigg]
$$

$A,\alpha,\gamma,\delta$ are constants.

In Cartesian coordinates, I could have assumed a solution form involving $\cos(f(z))$ because of the homogeneous Neumann boundaries along the $z$-direction. Can some one suggest such an alternative in the Cylindrical coordinate system. Additionally, how to deal with the integral type boundary conditions at $r=a_1$ ?

---

**Supporting information**
The boundary condition at $r=a_1$ is of third kind (Robin)
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \vert_{r=a_1}=\delta(T-T_f)
$$
where $T_f$ is evaluated as
$$
\frac{\partial T_f}{\partial z} + \alpha (T_f - T(r,z))=0 \Rightarrow T_f=e^{-\alpha z}\int e^{\alpha z} T \mathrm{d}z \\ \Rightarrow T_f=\alpha e^{-\alpha z} \Bigg[\int_0^z e^{\alpha s}T(r,s)\mathrm{d}s+\frac{A}{\alpha}\Bigg]
$$
$T_f(z=0)=A$ is known

Comment: As a shot in the dark, it may help to solve for $T_f$ in terms of $T$ and $\partial T/\partial r$ and then substitute into $T_f$'s equation.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The _supporting information_ section in my text tries to do that.  Here I have evaluated $T_f$ in terms of $T$ and then substituted in the boundary condition at $r=a_1$. Is this what you are suugesting ?